# In C, How can i store received rtp packets into .pcap file - UDP

Tags: c, sockets, rtp, packets

i need to store rtp packets that are received using recvfrom() into .pcap file.

I tried to open a file with the extension of .pcap and done direct fwrite whatever i received (ie void *buf), but when i tried to open that file using wireshark it given error statement as "not understandable"
What i'm supposed to do to make it as understandable??

Code i used:

```
recvfrom(sockfd, buf, len, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr->ss, &src_addr->len);
fp=fopen("test.pcap","a+");
fprintf(fp, "%s",buf);
```

In UDP connection how can i receive and store rtp packets into understandable .pcap file?
Is there anything extra need to be added with the received rtp pcakets?

Comment: Don't use `fprintf` for this. Use `fwrite`.

Comment: You can read the [libpcapFileFormat](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat).  The .pcap file requires some file headers for it to be understandable by wireshark.

Comment: I tried fprintf as well as fwrite, both were not working @Qix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the below headers in order to write the packets as pcap file.

Global Header

```
This header starts the libpcap file and will be followed by the first packet header:

   typedef struct pcap_hdr_s {
            guint32 magic_number;   /* magic number */
            guint16 version_major;  /* major version number */
            guint16 version_minor;  /* minor version number */
            gint32  thiszone;       /* GMT to local correction */
            guint32 sigfigs;        /* accuracy of timestamps */
            guint32 snaplen;        /* max length of captured packets, in octets */
            guint32 network;        /* data link type */
    } pcap_hdr_t;
```

Record (Packet) Header :

```
Each captured packet starts with (any byte alignment possible):

typedef struct pcaprec_hdr_s {
        guint32 ts_sec;         /* timestamp seconds */
        guint32 ts_usec;        /* timestamp microseconds */
        guint32 incl_len;       /* number of octets of packet saved in file */
        guint32 orig_len;       /* actual length of packet */
} pcaprec_hdr_t;
```

Check the [link](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/structpcap__file__header.html) for explanation of Headers.

Check this [link](http://www.ece.iit.edu/~dshila/links.html) for sample snippet of code.